# calling code from another php file (advanced)

Tags: php

I have 2 PHP files, one called `booking_functions.php` and the other `discount.php`

In `discount.php` I set 3 variables that are called across multiple pages dependent on what page is being called

In `booking_functions.php` i need to take the variables created in `discount.php` and pass them to a multidimensional array.

The issue is that the condition to set the array also sets the `$page_name`, but I am assuming it does not update `discount.php`, so therefore never fires and gets the correct function elements.

There are PHP tags around everything, and the user session is initialized.

```
//pages specific to an activity, there are over 30
     $page_name = "Hiking";
     include ("discount.php");
```

Then

```
// discount.php
    if($page_name == "Hiking"){
      $discount ="some var";
      $non_discount ="some var"; 
      $savings = $non_discount - $discount;
     }

    if($page_name == "kayaking"){
      $discount ="some var"; 
      $non_discount ="some var"; 
      $savings = $non_discount - $discount;
     }
     // etc. 
     // returns the discount value 
     function get_discount(){return $discount;}
```

Then

```
 //booking_functions.php

    include ("discount.php");
    // a html form button that adds a multidimensional session array 
    if(isset($_POST["sports_add"])){

    // checks to see what was selected 
    $drop_sport = $_POST['sports_add_dropdown'];

    // there are around 30 of these checks creating arrays 
    if($drop_sport=='hiking_d'){
    $page_name = "Hiking";
    $price = get_discount();
    // add array item
    $activity_array=array(0 =>array(
    'i_locked'=>false,
    'i_name' =>'Hiking',
    'i_people'=>1,
    'i_price'=>$price,
    'i_sport_activity'=> 'sport',
    'i_base_price'=>$price
    ));}
    $_SESSION["activity"][] = $activity_array;
    }
```

The way I hacked it was to use `include("discount.php");` after the `$page_name` was set in each function inside `booking_functions.php`, but I think this could be structured better.

Comment: `return $discount` is out of scope

Comment: "advanced"?! You better say "beginner".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, @ghost was right, just had to do the digging in the declaration of scope for PHP.

Here is the updated code that now works, with the original code, didn't get a chance to test Renato's code, but i will probably come back and see how his answer might improve the overall efficiency of the code and best practices.

What happens is all the discount variables get turned into a function that takes the `$page_name` variable as an argument. It now works across all 30 pages and the external section that needed to call `Booking_function.php`

I also re-factored the code, so that the added multidimensional items are 1 function instead of 30.

```
//discount.php 

    function get_discount($page_name){
    global $non_discounted, $discounted, $savings;

    if($page_name =="Hiking"){
    $discounted= "some var";
    $non_discounted = "some var";
    $savings= $non_discounted - $discounted;
    }

    if($page_name =="Kayaking"){
    $discounted= "some var";
    $non_discounted = "some var";
    $savings= $non_discounted - $discounted;
    }
```

Then

```
//booking_function.php 

    include ("discount.php");

    // a html form button that adds a multidimensional session array 
    if(isset($_POST["sports_add"])){

    // checks to see what was selected 
    $drop_sport = $_POST['sports_add_dropdown'];

    // call the function from discount passing in the variable to check
    // then call whichever global variable was updated.  
    get_discount("Hiking");
    $price = $non_discounted;

    // add array item
    $activity_array=array(0 =>array(
    'i_locked'=>false,
    'i_name' => $drop_sport,
    'i_people'=>1,
    'i_price'=>$price,
    'i_sport_activity'=> 'sport',
    'i_base_price'=>$price
    ));
    $_SESSION["activity"][] = $activity_array;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

How if you use class for this?
So it become like

```
class Discount
{
    private $discount;
    private $non_discount;
    private $savings;
    public function __construct ( $type ) {
        switch($type)
        {
            case "Hiking":
                $this->discount = "some var";
                $this->non_discount = "some var";
                $this->savings = $this->non_discount - $this->discount;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    public function get_discount()
    {
        return $this->discount;
    }
}
```

And for the booking function, you can use this

```
include ("Discount.php");
$discount = new Discount();
$discount->get_discount();
```

Comment: Hey Renato, Thanks for looking at it, i can see this being a solution, but i can't see how would this handle multiple variables, e.g. Hiking, Kayaking etc. 
Also can the switch type take in a check for if . The $page_name variable checks which page the person is currently viewing. This sets which case the code should go to get the variables needed in booking function